# i have a string datetime i want to insert into my database but i seem to get a syntax error doing it

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string of the date

```
$date = '2012-11-18 23:15:12';
```

and i want to insert it into my database.

```
create table A (
    t_date datetime
);
```

but it doesnt seem to work when i say

```
$q = "insert into A (t_date) values ('".$date."')";
mysql_query($q) or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
```

but when i do this, it returns an error related to $date and the query.

Should i use Timestamp instead of datetime?  How would i make it so it does insert correctly?

The Error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2012-11-18 23:15:12')' at line 1[roo
```

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Comment: general tip: if you get an error message and mention getting that error message, TELL US what the error message is. your code, as posted here, is fine.

Comment: Tested, [no error](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e282/1).

Comment: Thank you for editing your post with the error msg :).  Your PHP *looks* OK.  SUGGESTION: echo "$q" before your mysql_query(), and see if it's actually the string you expect.

Comment: ALSO: you might think about updating your code to use [MySQLI](http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2011/using-mysql-stored-procedures-with-php-mysqli/) or PDO.  The ["mysql_query"](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) syntax is deprecated.  It might not be practical for you, but it's certainly worth considering.  IMHO...

Comment: When i did an echo, it was putting an additional comma into stuff.  I fixed it and it seemed to work.  There is another error that i just got that i need to look at. "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: Q: Where was the comma coming from?  Q: Is there any chance the *same* comma (in $t_date?) might be causing the *same* error now?

Comment: The additional comma came from the addition of other variables in the inside insert values()..  The item being inserted was the empty string and therefore was doing something along the lines of:  "insert into ... () values (0,,t_date); which was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the current date to a string use the CURDATE to do that job for you in MySQL.

```
$q = "INSERT INTO A (col_name, col_date) VALUE ('DATETIME: Auto CURDATE()', CURDATE() )";
mysql_query($q) or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
```

Checkout this link for the list of DATE TIME functionalities in MySQL.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate

Comment: I saw that example.  It didnt make a lot of sense to me.  Otherwise i would not have asked the question.

Comment: And more to the point, maybe the OP didn't *intend* to insert current date/time?  PS: My preference is to use *SQL* to insert the date (e.g. `NOW()`). It's usually better for the *server* to manage "now", than for clients.  This is especially true if you happen to have multiple clients in multiple time zones.  Admittedly not the case here - but definitely a good practice.  IMHO...

Comment: no, definately not.  There is a XML doc which has a datetime as a part of a transaction.... and i wanted to keep track of the datetime, which is up to 1 month in the past

Comment: for some reason date was being stored in the DB despite datetime as ready as the definition.  For dropping and rebuilding fixed... and all datetimes started to work